# pymc-learn: RuntimeError in JupterLab 1.2.6

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, pymc3

I am learning to use pymc-learn. However, whenever I try to run an MCMC simulation with pymc-learn in JupterLab 1.2.6 , I get the following RuntimeError:

```
RuntimeError: The communication pipe between the main process and its spawned children is broken.

In Windows OS, this usually means that the child process raised an exception while it was being spawned, before it was setup to communicate to the main process.
The exceptions raised by the child process while spawning cannot be caught or handled from the main process, and when running from an IPython or jupyter notebook interactive kernel, the child's exception and traceback appears to be lost.
A known way to see the child's error, and try to fix or handle it, is to run the problematic code as a batch script from a system's Command Prompt. The child's exception will be printed to the Command Promt's stderr, and it should be visible above this error and traceback.

Note that if running a jupyter notebook that was invoked from a Command Prompt, the child's exception should have been printed to the Command Prompt on which the notebook is running.
```

As an example, I am using a copy-paste from the 'LinearRegression' example of the pymc-learn

```
model2 = LinearRegression()
model2.fit(X_train, y_train, inference_type='nuts')
```

How to deal with this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it might relate to your operating system. I encountered similar issue with Windows. Try to reduce the amount of core to 1 with using `cores` function before sampling. Hope it will help.